# _.pick for collections (underscore/lodash)

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

Is there a lodash function where you can create a collection from an other one by picking only specified attributes?

```
stats = [{a:1, b:1}, {a:2, b:2}]
reducedStats = _.pick(stats, 'a'); // now is [{a:1},{a:2}]
```

The normal `pick` only works for objects, not for collections.

I achieved it with

```
stats = stats.map(_.partialRight(_.pick, 'a'));
```

which is somewhat verbose.

Comment: No, using `map` is just what you should do. Unless you want to do a `_.pluck(stats, 'a')`

Comment: No, that does not work. In the real usecase I need two properties ;).

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd love to hear a solution if you found one.

Comment: No, I used the verbose version.

Comment: What if you want to *pick* the entire object from one collection if its `id` matches, and add it to the other collection -- basically, using one `.map` call? Is there a resource/pattern for this?

Answer (score 2):

In my example here, I add a method called `make` that does your task.

```
var _ = require('lodash');
_.make = (arr, ...args) => arr.map(obj => _.pick(obj, args));
```

Comment: you can use `pick` in line 4 like I did. That would simplify things